# Create JSON WebService using only JSP Page

Tags: jsp, java

I want to create JSON WebService using only JSP Page.
For this I want to do everthing in one JSP file.

I follow the below steps :

File > New > Dynamic Web Project with name "test"

Create New file in "WebContent" folder with name "test.jsp"

"test.jsp" file code mentioned below

```
<%@ page import="javax.ws.rs.POST"%>
<%@ page import="javax.ws.rs.Path"%>
<%@ page import="javax.ws.rs.core.Response"%>
<%@ page import="javax.ws.rs.Consumes"%>
<%@ page import="javax.ws.rs.Produces"%>
<%@ page import="org.json.JSONObject"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.Date"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.TimeZone"%>
<%@ page import="java.text.DateFormat"%>
<%@ page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>

@Path("/")
<%!
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    SimpleDateFormat returnDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
    @POST
    @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    @Path("/Register")
    public Response Register(String json) {
        Date dt = new Date();
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
        String currentTime = formatter.format(dt);
        JSONObject returnJson = new JSONObject();
        try {
            JSONObject innerJsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
            String email = innerJsonObj.getString("email");

            JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject();
            jsonData.put("id", email);
            returnJson.put("success", true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JSONObject errorJson = new JSONObject();
            errorJson.put("success", false);
            return Response.ok(errorJson.toString()).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").build();
        }
        return Response.ok(returnJson.toString()).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").build();
    }
%>
```

my "web.xml" file code is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>test</display-name>
</web-app>
```

**When I Right click on "test" Project and run on server then it gives the following error**

```
HTTP Status 404 - /test/
```

**When I post JSON using Chrome Rest Web Service Client plugin
JSON Data with "http://localhost:8080/test/Register" URL**

```
{"email": "test@xyz.com"}
```

It gives the following response

```
404, Not Found
Date: Wed, 28 Sep 2016 12:06:00 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Length: 1036
Content-Language: en
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
```

My Tomcat 8 Server Log :

```
Sep 28, 2016 5:01:46 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:test' did not find a matching property.
Sep 28, 2016 5:01:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.33
Sep 28, 2016 5:01:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Mar 18 2016 20:31:49 UTC
Sep 28, 2016 5:01:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.33.0
Sep 28, 2016 5:01:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 8.1
Sep 28, 2016 5:01:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.3
Sep 28, 2016 5:01:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Sep 28, 2016 5:01:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre
Sep 28, 2016 5:01:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_45-b15
Sep 28, 2016 5:01:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Sep 28, 2016 5:01:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         D:\Documents\Eclipse_Workspace\test\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Sep 28, 2016 5:01:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
Sep 28, 2016 5:01:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=D:\Documents\Eclipse_Workspace\test\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Sep 28, 2016 5:01:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
Sep 28, 2016 5:01:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=D:\Documents\Eclipse_Workspace\test\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Sep 28, 2016 5:01:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\endorsed
Sep 28, 2016 5:01:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Sep 28, 2016 5:01:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_45/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_45/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_45/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\WINDOWS\System32;;.
Sep 28, 2016 5:01:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Sep 28, 2016 5:01:47 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Sep 28, 2016 5:01:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Sep 28, 2016 5:01:47 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Sep 28, 2016 5:01:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2795 ms
Sep 28, 2016 5:01:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 28, 2016 5:01:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.33
Sep 28, 2016 5:01:49 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Sep 28, 2016 5:01:49 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Sep 28, 2016 5:01:49 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Sep 28, 2016 5:01:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2356 ms
```

I am using Eclipse Mars1, Tomcat 8 and jdk1.8.0_45.

Comment: _I want to create JSON WebService using only JSP Page_ Why? What is the reason behind this? It would be the most poor programming practice.

Comment: @Simze I have to deploy this jsp file in one third party tool for some reason. So thats why i have to create same.

Comment: There are so many things wrong with this it's hard to know where to start.

Comment: @AlanHay please start from anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

This is a weird structure. It depends on how tomcat is setup to compile the jsp's. Quite often, this is done lazily, i.e. the first time they are necessary.

At start of the application (and, as far as I know, only then), scanning of the classpath is done to find the JAX-RS annotations and bind them.

So you see why it doesn't (and probably will never) work.